# CSS cropping img in a div from left

Tags: css, image

If an image overflows its container and I want to crop it, it's easy enough from the right (the default action is that the image is anchored to the top left of the div) and there are various ways of cropping to the centre.

What I would like to do is crop from the left. In other words so that the image is anchored to the top and right of the enclosing div.

Needless to say I need a solution that works without knowing the div width and although I will know the image width, I don't see how this helps.

I can see the background image solution to this issue but it would be nice to use the image as an element so I can apply retina images. It would also be nice not to have to use Javascript.

Any ideas, hive mind?

If I come up with a partial solution I will paste the code but at the moment I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you can try,  `{
    direction: rtl;
}`

Comment: @user5542121 That's the kind of solution I like, simple, humorous even. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox and adjust the alignment:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:20px;
  display:inline-flex;
  vertical-align:top;
  /* overflow:hidden uncomment this to hide the overflow*/
  border:1px solid;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
img {
 opacity:0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150?image=1069" >
</div>
<div class="box" style="align-items:center;justify-content:center;">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150?image=1069" >
</div>
<div class="box" style="align-items:flex-end;">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150?image=1069" >
</div>
<div class="box" style="align-items:flex-end;justify-content:flex-end;">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150?image=1069" >
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Flexbox can do that

```css
div {
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* toggel to see overflow */
}

img {
  display: block;
  opacity: .5/* to show overflow */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="">
</div>
```