# Make elements overlap on left side and align to right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Normally, when an element overflows from its parent, it overflows on the right side, while aligning to the left.

Is there a way to reverse this, so overlapping elements align to the right side, and overlap on left? I am trying to apply this overlap to each child element of an element containing multiple inline elements.

This is not a duplicate of [CSS cropping img in a div from left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324231/css-cropping-img-in-a-div-from-left/51324429#51324429) as I am trying to apply this to an element containing multiple inline elements.

Comment: yes, `justify-content:flex-end`

Comment: another duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324231/css-cropping-img-in-a-div-from-left/51324429#51324429 (cannot add to the list because no upvotes)

Comment: This solution solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48481315/1253298

Comment: pay attention to the `rtl` solution I don't recommend it ;) you can read my comments in the same page for another answer

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481284/css-styling-to-show-end-of-single-text-string/48481315#48481315, as confirmed by OP.